# Kill FINished sockets (using libpcap - tcpdump/tcpkill)

Tags: perl, tcpdump, pcap, java

I'm trying to create a small service that monitors and kills sockets which have the **FIN** flag. I can get them with **tcpdump** (I also tried tcp[13] & 1):

```
tcpdump "tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-fin != 0"
```

**tcpkill** is suppose to use the same interface as **tcpdump**, but it isn't working the same. I've tried a bunch of commands, but it should just be (-i eth0 optional):

```
tcpkill -9 "tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-fin != 0"
```

Which says (but nothing else, successful **tcpkill** outputs data):

> tcpkill: listening on eth0 [tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-fin != 0]

Looking at the source, it should be passing the correct filter to pcap (between the [ ] brackets). Using a perl script with **Net::Pcap** I can determine the filter works fine. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or if it's an older version of tcpkill/pcap that's an issue. Any help with tcpkill or help using perl's **Net::Pcap** to kill sockets would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::Pcap;

my $err = '';
my $dev = 'eth0';

my ($address, $netmask);
Net::Pcap::lookupnet($dev, \$address, \$netmask, \$err);

my $pcap = Net::Pcap::open_live($dev, 1500, 1, 0, \$err);

my $filter;
Net::Pcap::compile($pcap, \$filter, "tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-fin != 0", 0, $netmask);
Net::Pcap::setfilter($pcap, $filter);

while(1)
{
 Net::Pcap::loop($pcap, 1, \&process_packet, "packet found");
}

Net::Pcap::close($pcap);

sub process_packet
{
 my($user_data, $header, $packet) = @_;
 print "$user_data\n";
}

exit 0;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the purpose or goal behind this?  If it's just "because I can" or "because I want to", that's cool.  But I'm wondering what the actual problem you're trying to solve is.  If you're just concerned with connections that you've FIN'ed and that haven't closed yet, changing OS TCP/IP paramters (like 'tcp_fin_timeout' on Linux) may be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source code for tcpkill](http://www.koders.com/c/fid05B05446657B94052F825BDDE730D0A60BCA56DA.aspx), it uses libnet to generate a RST packet(s) to kill a given TCP connection.  I'm not sure why it's not working (though verifying the PCAP version it was built against is a great place to start).  You can also use tcpdump to look for the RST packets it should be sending out.

Regarding implementing the equivalent in Perl, I once had to do something sort of similar.  Below is (untested!) code which might point you in the right direction.

```
use NetPacket::Ethernet;
use NetPacket::IP;
use NetPacket::TCP;
use Net::RawIP;

... (the rest of your script) ...

sub process_packet {
    my ($user_data,$header,$packet) = @_;

    my $ethernet_frame = NetPacket::Ethernet::strip($packet);
    my $ip_packet = NetPacket::IP->decode($ethernet_frame);
    my $tcp = NetPacket::TCP->decode($ip_packet->{data});

    my $reset_packet = new Net::RawIP;

    $reset_packet->set({
        ip => {
            saddr => $ip_packet->{dest_ip},
            daddr => $ip_packet->{src_ip}
        },
        tcp => {
            source => $tcp->{dest_port},
            dest => $tcp->{src_port}
        },
        rst => 1,
        seq => $ip->{acknum},
        data => 'access denied'
    });

    $reset_packet->send();
}
```

tcpkill is more refined in terms of attempting to figure out the correct sequence number, which is what the -1..9 flags are for.  Have you tried using different values for that flag?

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I started using pycap, which seemed to be working at least half the time, but I wasn't sure. I'm going to give these suggestions a try (perl and figuring out sequence).

Something I was wondering is if I should ONLY be sending the RST packet to the OTHER servers, or just my server, or both my server and the others? tcpkill seems to just reverse the destination and source? Would that be circular?

Comment: When you say you want to "kill FINished sockets", what is your goal?  What OS are you using?

With tcpkill, you're only initiating a tear down of the TCP session.  After the RST is sent, you're waiting on the TCP/IP stack timers to clear out the resources on the local end.

Alternatively, BSD systems have a utility called 'tcpdrop', which instruct the kernel to drop the connection.  It too initiates a RST packet, but alleviates the need to figure out the correct TCP sequence number in user space (i.e. the TCP/IP stack knows).  It also seems to be quicker about clearing out the local resources.